# What is the difference between multiple patterns and multiple match clauses?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

What is the difference between

```
match (v:player)--(n),(n:team)--(m) return count(m)
```

and

```
match (v:player)--(n) match (n:team)--(m) return count(m)
```

I profiled these two statements and found that the edges of multiple patterns in the previous statement were not allowed to repeat.

I used to think that the path mode only constrained a single path, and there should be no such restriction among multiple path patterns, but this is not consistent with my current test results.

How does that make sense？

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j uses *Relationship Isomorphism* when matching path when using single statement [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/introduction/uniqueness/):

> Cypher path matching uses relationship isomorphism, the same relationship cannot be returned more than once in the same result record.
> So yes you can use multiple `MATCH` to return results you don't get with single path matching.

In provided documentation you can see similar example to yours and it is stated that syntax with single `MATCH` and comma is equivalent with multiple `MATCH`, so you used in second example just different syntax, but you are not matching single path. If you want to see difference you must define this like single path

```
match (v:player)--(n:team)--(m) return count(m)
```

Comment: So, the multiple path pattern separated by commas in the single match statement is still called `single path matching`, which needs to satisfy the constraint of the path mode with non-repeating edges?

Comment: No you provided two paths. So first you match every player, after that you match everything if `n` is labeled as `team`. When you define single path it looks similar. But it will not connect two times same player for example if you have something like this in database: `John--Arsenal--John` your query can match this path, but single path query can't because one relationship can be returned only once in single path. Last example in documentation I provided is this example.

Comment: @zpc You have identical example in documentation on link I provided.

Comment: I know what you mean. I just want to understand why Relationship Isomorphism(also called `a type of path mode` by Gql standard) is for a single match statement rather than a single path pattern, and why is it designed like this.

Comment: @zpc I'm not sure about your last comment. Cypher for Neo4J is designed to be easy to learn with syntax similar with SQL. I think that is one reason, with multiple `MATCH` you can create results similar like using multiple `JOIN`s in SQL.